# How to write a sql query for below requirement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, case

| AgencyId | SourceType | SourceCode | PropertyState | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz1 | NULL | test1 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz2 | NULL | test2 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz3 | NULL | test3 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz4 | NULL | test4 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz5 | NULL | test5 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz6 | NULL | test6 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz7 | NULL | test7 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz8 | NULL | test8 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz9 | NULL | test9 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz10 | NULL | test10 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz11 | NULL | test11 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz12 | NULL | test12 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz13 | NULL | test13 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz14 | NULL | test14 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz15 | NULL | test15 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz16 | NULL | test16 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz17 | NULL | test17 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz18 | NULL | test18 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz19 | NULL | test19 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz20 | NULL | test20 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz21 | NULL | test21 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz22 | NULL | test22 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz23 | NULL | test23 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz24 | NULL | test24 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz25 | NULL | test25 |
| a1002 | NULL | Xyz26 | NULL | test26 |
| a1003 | NULL | Xyz27 | FL | test27 |
| a1003 | NULL | Xyz28 | NULL | test28 |
| a1004 | NULL | NULL | NULL | test29 |
| a1005 | NULL | NULL | NULL | test30 |
| a1006 | NULL | NULL | FL | test31 |
| a1006 | NULL | NULL | NULL | test32 |
| a1007 | NULL | NUL**L | NULL | test33 |
| a1008 | B | NULL | NULL | test34 |
| a1008 | O | NULL | NULL | test35 |

I have a table name test,in that there are 5 columns `AgencyId,SourceType,SourceCode,PropertyStae,Code`

Want to write sql query which will give Code as output base on following drilldown logic

First match by `AgencyId,SourceCode,PropertyState` if not then `AgencyId,SourceCode` if not then `AgencyId,SourceType` if not then `AgencyId PropertyStae` if not then `SourceType PropertyState` if not then only by AgencyId.

How to write sql query for this. Requirement is such that can not write sp nor functions. Kindly let me know about the solution

Comment: use a case expression assign a number based on which condition is/are met 1-6 .  e.g. `Case when agencyID = ::agencyID and sourceCode = ::sourceCode and propertystae = ::propertystae and code = ::code then 1 else when ... else 7 end as ConditionMet`  if condition is 1-6 then one of your conditions has been met, if condition 7 then none have been met.  you could use this in the select and the where clause to limit data as needed.  note ::Variable are parameters passed in as an example...

Answer (score 1):

You could translate the requirement to a serie of `OR` & `AND`

For example

```
DECLARE 
 @AgencyId varchar(8) = 'a1002', 
 @SourceCode varchar(8) = 'Xyz1', 
 @SourceType char(1) = 'B', 
 @PropertyState char(2) = 'FL';
 
SELECT *
, CASE 
  WHEN AgencyId = @AgencyId 
   AND SourceCode = @SourceCode 
   AND PropertyState = @PropertyState
   THEN 'match 1'
  WHEN AgencyId = @AgencyId 
   AND SourceCode = @SourceCode 
   THEN 'match 2'
  WHEN AgencyId = @AgencyId 
   AND SourceType = @SourceType
   THEN 'match 3'
  WHEN AgencyId = @AgencyId
   AND PropertyState = @PropertyState
   THEN 'match 4'
  WHEN SourceType = @SourceType 
   AND PropertyState = @PropertyState
   THEN 'match 5'
  WHEN AgencyId = @AgencyId
   THEN 'match 6'
  ELSE 'no match'
  END AS Match
FROM test
WHERE (AgencyId = @AgencyId AND SourceCode = @SourceCode AND PropertyState = @PropertyState)
 OR (AgencyId = @AgencyId AND SourceCode = @SourceCode) 
 OR (AgencyId = @AgencyId AND SourceType = @SourceType)
 OR (AgencyId = @AgencyId AND PropertyState = @PropertyState)
 OR (SourceType = @SourceType AND PropertyState = @PropertyState)
 OR (AgencyId = @AgencyId)
```

But those criteria can be simplified :

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE (AgencyId = @AgencyId 
   OR (SourceType = @SourceType AND PropertyState = @PropertyState)
);
```

> | AgencyId | SourceType | SourceCode | PropertyState | Code |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | a1002 | *null* | Xyz1 | FL | test1 |
> | a1002 | *null* | Xyz1 | *null* | test2 |
> | a1002 | B | *null* | *null* | test3 |
> | a1002 | *null* | *null* | FL | test4 |
> | *null* | B | *null* | FL | test5 |
> | a1002 | *null* | *null* | *null* | test6 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=af507e0407dcaa704c7cf07dbd34baf8)*

Comment: LukStorms i did not understood how case is working here. Select case then match is there match 1,match 2,match 3 upto match 6 and after from table name and where condition. Please let me know about the same

Comment: It's simple. A case will return at the first condition that evaluates as true. So  `case when 0=1 then 0 when 1=1 then 1 when 2=2 then 2 else 3 end`  would return 1.

Comment: facing a issue when sourcecode is Xyz1 and AgencyId is a1002 output should be first row that is test1,but here i am getting all the rows where AgencyId a1002. Need code by AgencyId only if it matches by agencyId and not by other that is propertystate,sourcecode,sourcetype. Stuck on this,please let me know how to do this